# Should I use MongoDB or Couchbase 2.x for simple between query?

Tags: mongodb, couchbase, nosql

I have about 200k documents like

```
{ min: 100, max: 200, name1: value1, name2: value2, ...}
```

I want to find the documents where my input would be a number which should fall within the min/max range.

Since this is a fixed and only search pattern and my application in ready heavy, which NoSQL should I prefer? Note that we are expecting a very high number (200-500) of concurrent queries in peak hours and virtually no writes. (This is a web server and writes if any can be schedules in off peak hours when there is no load on server.) Another point is a need of replication on each of my web server - to avoid network queries from one server to another - which I believe is supported by both. Few of my applications are in Apache-PHP and few are in Tomcat-Java, all running off Linux system. I am more inclined towards Couchbase as it uses memcached (in-memory), but developer communities like SO has far greater support for MongoDB. Is there any other option that I should explore?

Comment: Do some performance tests with your data. It's really hard to say. I'd suggest dumping a bunch of RAM on the web servers and doing the search locally if you're concerned about performance. I don't understand what your comment about replication means. You won't run your web server on the database server, will you?

Comment: This is not exactly a database server, but a filter to web application. Used mostly in case of IP/CIDR filtering, IP to Geolocation, ISP detection etc. Running on web server will eliminate whatever latency that may arise if on different machine.

Comment: You can try to use [cbworkloadgen](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-getting-started-testing-cbworkloadgen.html) to test couchbase. There are also some tests that compare mongoDB and couchbase: [1](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/04/NoSQL-Benchmark), [2](http://www.slideshare.net/renatko/couchbase-performance-benchmarking)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already went threw most of the benchmarks comparing these two. What I would like to know is which one would better suite for my use case based on experience of existing users. I am also setting up both MongoDB and Couchbase on my test systems to do a test run.

Comment: Can you clarify the statement " is a need of replication on each of my web server", most of time the data are distributed (shards) in all nodes of your cluster.

Comment: @TugGrall Well sharding is useful when data size is more than certain limit. Why shard when my whole data can leave in-memory of single instance? And doing a replication will also save on Network IO over sockets, however small it may be. This is to be developed for performance under high load. I am going my testing, will update here once done.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done a short review of the respective merits of MongoDb and CouchBase.
The most important thing is that there are more similarities than differences, and both are good products that would work well in most cases.

I will sum up the differences by saying that MongoDB is generally easier to install, use, and query (plus it has a larger community as you say), whereas CouchBase goes the extra mile for performance(memcache and insert throughput), auto-scaling, and recovery from failure.

Personally given a situation like yours of a (presumably) new app with a query requirement and virtually no write, I would go with **MongoDB**. It would be faster to get it to work and there would be solutions to optimize reads down the road if you'd need to.